# How to convert object of class into hexadecimal array in java

Tags: java, hex, byte, smartcard, javacard

An object of class having some data and I am gone write that object into java card.
I am having a function that convert hexadecimal data into byte array and then write that data to smart card using java card.
While i convert data into hex format i encrypt that data. 
So i need to convert object of class into hexadecimal.
Please tell me how to convert object into Hex format in java.

I am using smart card type = contact card using java card 2.2.2 with jcop using apdu.

Comment: A serialized object contains alot of overhead. Using JavaCards it is preferrable to reduce the data to a minimum before writing it to the card. There I would not use object serialization. Use a DataOutputStream instead and write just the data using your own format.

Comment: OK, then simple for you: Object serialization is very very inefficient. Data transmissions between JavaCard and Terminal are slow and usually limited to blocks of 256 bytes. Hence much data + slow transfer = bad design (IMHO). It is much better to save all method fields on your own by writing them to a DataOutputStream.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here i am sending you program which converts objects to byte array and vice versa.

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.util.Date;

public class Sandbox {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      // convert object to bytes
      Date d1 = new Date();
      System.out.println(d1);
      ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
      oos.writeObject(d1);
      byte[] buf = baos.toByteArray();

      // convert back from bytes to object
      ObjectInputStream ois =
        new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(buf));
      Date d2 = (Date) ois.readObject();
      ois.close();

      System.out.println(d2);
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
      ioe.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
      cnfe.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use [serialization](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/serialization/) but to serialize an object a (that) class must be serializable. Have a look at - [Java Object Serialization Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serialTOC.html).

Comment: can someone tell me another solution.

Answer (score 2):

Here You can convert class object to byte array as

```
    public byte[] toByteArray (Object obj)
    {
      byte[] bytes = null;
      ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      try {
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos); 
        oos.writeObject(obj);
        oos.flush(); 
        oos.close(); 
        bos.close();
        bytes = bos.toByteArray ();
      }
      catch (IOException ex) {
        //TODO: Handle the exception
  }
  return bytes;
}
```

Comment: Whether its working in your application?Or you want any other information?

Comment: It return object size or location.I want object with all data member with their data.Is it possible to store object with data ?

Comment: @SachinDalvi : It returns the BYTE array.How u r saying "It return object size"?

Comment: it return byte array of that object but it doesn't contain data.when i add more data to it's data member it return same data in byte array.