# How to edit tinyblob date in mysql?

Tags: mysql, date, blob

I'm working on a legacy application with MySQL DB.

Here's the relevant table:

```
RESERVATION
============
id: int
creation_date: tinyblob
...other stuff...
```

When the entity is created, the `creation_date` is calculated using Java's `LocalDate.now()`.

When I select the data from the table (in MySQL Workbench), I see only "`BLOB`" in the creation_date column. When I click "Open value in editor", I get something like:

```
¬í sr 
java.time.Ser]º"H²  xpw  àx
```

When I double click the field, nothing happens, it won't let me enter the editing mode.

Is there any way to directly edit the date stored like this? I could create a Java function that will insert some dates other than `LocalDate.now()`, but it would be easier to do this manually in the Workbench (or some other application). Since this is a legacy software, I'm not able to alter the column type.

Tnx.

Comment: A date in a tinyblob?? I would love to know that reason for that!

Comment: @RiggsFolly me too... but I have to use it now, there's no alternative...

Comment: `SELECT HEX(creation_date)`, compare that value to the known time value it represents, while reading the underlying source code that defines the structure, and write stored functions to manipulate this binary structure in MySQL.  Horribly messy, but conceivably possible.  Anything that can be packed can be unpacked, twizzled, tweaked, and repacked with enough gyrations... but there's no simple answer.

Comment: @RiggsFolly   java.time.Instant are stored as tinyblob in mysql using Hibernate

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution. This guy helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8504540/1177067 
Create a new class which extends AttributeConverter:

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import javax.persistence.AttributeConverter;
import javax.persistence.Converter;

@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class LocalDateTimeAttributeConverter implements AttributeConverter<LocalDateTime, Object> {

@Override
public Object convertToDatabaseColumn(LocalDateTime locDateTime) {
    return locDateTime == null ? null : Timestamp.valueOf(locDateTime);
}

@Override
public LocalDateTime convertToEntityAttribute(Object sqlTimestamp) {
    if (sqlTimestamp != null) {
        try {
            byte[] dbBytes = (byte[]) sqlTimestamp;
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(dbBytes));
            LocalDateTime covertedDateFromBytes = (LocalDateTime) ois.readObject();
            ois.close();
            return covertedDateFromBytes;
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
            cnfe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

Be aware that:

```
@Override
public Object convertToDatabaseColumn(LocalDateTime locDateTime) {
    return locDateTime == null ? null : Timestamp.valueOf(locDateTime);
}
```

is storing the date in a new way (as a Timestamp) so decide if you might want to go with the tinyblob further or use a new approach with Timestamp.