# How to convert MySQL TINYBLOB to LocalDateTime?

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, jpa, blob, localdate

JPA and MySQL convert:

```
@Column(name = "registration_date")
private LocalDateTime registrationDate;
```

to TINYBLOB column type.

Now the MySQL database is full of dates in TINYBLOB.

What is the proper way to deal with this in the new Spring Boot v2.2.5?

Should all TINYBLOB columns be somehow converted into an any other date type directly in the MySQL db?
Should AttributeConverter interface be used to convert while fetching the date from the db?

```
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class LocalDateTimeAttributeConverter implements AttributeConverter<LocalDateTime, Object> {

   @Override
   public Object convertToDatabaseColumn(LocalDateTime locDateTime) {
       return locDateTime == null ? null : Timestamp.valueOf(locDateTime);
   }

   @Override
   public LocalDateTime convertToEntityAttribute(Object tinyBlob) {
       if (sqlTimestamp != null) {
           // somehow convert tinyblob to LocalDateTime?
       }
       return null;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution. This guy helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8504540/1177067

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import javax.persistence.AttributeConverter;
import javax.persistence.Converter;

@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class LocalDateTimeAttributeConverter implements AttributeConverter<LocalDateTime, Object> {

@Override
public Object convertToDatabaseColumn(LocalDateTime locDateTime) {
    return locDateTime == null ? null : Timestamp.valueOf(locDateTime);
}

@Override
public LocalDateTime convertToEntityAttribute(Object sqlTimestamp) {
    if (sqlTimestamp != null) {
        try {
            byte[] dbBytes = (byte[]) sqlTimestamp;
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(dbBytes));
            LocalDateTime covertedDateFromBytes = (LocalDateTime) ois.readObject();
            ois.close();
            return covertedDateFromBytes;
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
            cnfe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Be aware that:

```
@Override
public Object convertToDatabaseColumn(LocalDateTime locDateTime) {
    return locDateTime == null ? null : Timestamp.valueOf(locDateTime);
}
```

is storing the date in a new way (as a Timestamp) so decide if you might want to go with the tinyblob further or use a new approach with Timestamp.